# Dual iPad deleting

Tags: ipad

I have two iPads, and want to give my adult daughter one. I don't want to clear it completely, leaving games and such on there for her. I need to clear off the mail and photos. Will this do that to my new iPad with the same mail and photos?

Comment: Do it correctly now-erase it fully and set it up again with a new appleid or her existing appleid from another device.  If you want her to be able to redownload purchased games set up family sharing, if it's a paid game she will not have to pay again. If you change the appleid on the iPad to hers without clearing the AppStore will complain if any of them need to be updated.  Do yourself a favor and do this correctly first time and that means clearing the iPad and starting over.  Appleids are not meant to be shared, if you do not take this advice now you will be back with more questions later.

Answer (score 1):

You could go through Settings and delete all the accounts under Mail, Contacts, Calendars, sign out of iCloud, iTunes and App Store. This should cover most of it. I think you're better off erasing the device and setting it up fresh though. You can always re-install the apps. If you use Family Sharing, she'll be able to install anything you've ever bought from iTunes.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201088

Comment: Thank you, but what I want to know is if it will affect my iPad Air2 when I do that?!!

Comment: Is the Family Sharing free? I didn't see it say anything about a fee! Thx

Comment: Family Sharing is free. Deleting apps/signing out of iCloud from one iPad will not affect the other one.